# How can I get a unique id from a multicolumn GridView with setOnItemClickListener so that I know which ImageView in a row the user clicked on?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I had to build a GridView that divides a group of imageviews up into 3 separate columns (and since there are a random number of imageviews it can be any number of rows). When a user clicks on one of the imageviews a specific action needs to be performed for each one.

I created the gridview using an adapter that extends BaseAdapter, linked to a layout file that contains the three imageviews for every row. Everything works fine, except that when a user clicks on one of the imageviews he only gets back the id for the *row* that he pressed on - there's no way of knowing which of the imageviews in the row he clicked on. For example, clicking on the first imageview returns a position of 0 and an id of 0. So does the second and the third. The fourth imageview (in the second row) already returns a position of 1 and an id of 1 and so on. I'd appreciate some sort of direction on this.

Code for displaying the gridview:

```
GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(context,list1,list2,list3);
gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

Log.d(ACTIVITY_TAG +".onCreate()","position was " +String.valueOf(position) +" long id was " +String.valueOf(id));
}});
```

Code for the gridadapter:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
 private ArrayList<Bitmap> listcol1;
 private ArrayList<Bitmap> listcol2;
 private ArrayList<Bitmap> listcol3;
 private Context context;

private ImageView img1;
private ImageView img2;
private ImageView img3;

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridAdapter(Context inpContext,ArrayList<Bitmap> listColumn1, ArrayList<Bitmap> listColumn2, ArrayList<Bitmap> listColumn3) {
    super();
    this.listcol1 = listColumn1;
    this.listcol2 = listColumn2;
    this.listcol3 = listColumn3;
    this.context = inpContext;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listcol1.size();
}

@Override
public Bitmap getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listcol1.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.d("GridAdapter.getView()","position was " +String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    }

    img1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cp_image1);
    img2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cp_image2);
    img3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cp_image3);

    if (position < listcol1.size()) {
        img1.setImageBitmap(listcol1.get(position));
    }

    if (position < listcol2.size()) {
        img2.setImageBitmap(listcol2.get(position));
    }

    if (position < listcol3.size()) {
        img3.setImageBitmap(listcol3.get(position));
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Code for the row layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/cp_image1"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/cp_image2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/cp_image3"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a TAG ([View.setTag(Object obj)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))) on each ImageView when it's recycled in your adapter.  That way, when the View is clicked, you can call View.getTag(), and retrieve the unique information you need about the view to handle the action correctly.  Since a tag is treated as an object, you can include as much or as little information as you need to do the job.

The other option would be to use the row number, and the R.id.__ of the ImageView to determine which ImageView was clicked.

The last thing I'm noticing, is that you're using your GridView more like ListView -- not an actual GridView.  A GridView would represent each ImageView as a separate entity, not as a row containing 3 image views.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm giving you best answer. If you have any suggestions as to how to rewrite the gridview so that its 3 imageviews and not one linearlayout of the row, and still show 3 imageviews to each row of the gridview, then I'm of course very grateful

Comment: Modify in the xml of your gridview the desired number of columns, so android:numColumns="3".  Then, instead of returning a LinearLayout of ImageViews, just return an image view for each getView() return.  If you want additional info on how to clean it up, you'll have to post a new question though since I can only explain a bit in a comment.

Comment: You're a lifesaver - everything works perfectly now. I can't thank you enough